# Where is Share button on a file in community?

Tags: customer-community, files

I have a question about file sharing in community. Basically, the question is why a community member (license: Customer Community Plus) doesn't see the Share option on the [File List](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_files_list.htm&type=0) component? A community member cannot share a file uploaded in the community with other community members/groups using the Share option on the File List component in the same community. The file was uploaded by the community user and is owned by this user. I have attached a screenshot that visualize my question.

[image]

I also have read this article [File Visibility and Sharing in Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_files_visibility_and_sharing.htm&type=5), but I still don't have a clue if community users can share files from the File List.

Comment: We ran into similar problem and sharing option is available only in classic. I forgot how exactly but we were able to get classic version of this page and it had share option.

Comment: I came across this Q&A because Salesforce's own documentation, ["Share Files with Groups"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_sharing_groups.htm&type=5), states that Community/Experience Cloud users don't have access to a share button if the file originated from a community or is viewed in an Experience Cloud site. I am looking to give this ability to my community users, but it sounds like it's only possible with a custom solution at this point.

Answer (score 2):

As of this post the current response from one of the Community Product Managers is this is working as expected and you need to share files in a Group or Feed by Posting on a Record.  I am continuing to discuss the scenario with him and hoping for a more thorough response after they find the team who owns this particular component.  I will update this Answer as new details come in.